# Delphi - How can I get a select from a twebbrowser into an array?

Tags: arrays, delphi, select, twebbrowser

I have the following select in my twebbrowser

```
<Select name="ship_to_method">
<option value="1941">Royal Mail Standard Delivery at £1.45 </option>
<option value="1942">Courier Standard Delivery  at £4.64 </option>
<option value="1943">Royal Mail Priority Delivery at £1.66 </option>
<option value="1944">Courier Priority Delivery at £5.15 </option>
</select>
```

the number of options and the values change dynamically,

how can i get the options into an array so I have..

```
option_ids=(1941,1942,1943,1944);

option_texts=("Royal Mail Standard Delivery at £1.45","Courier Standard Delivery  at £4.64","Royal Mail Priority Delivery at £1.66","Courier Priority Delivery at £5.15");
```

if anyone has any code to share that would be great!

many thanks

Stu

Comment: The key is getting hold of the data, and that's actually easy using the DOM. Using `(TWebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2)` you get a [IHTMLDocument2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, follow the link for the documentation.

Comment: The best reference for TWebBrowser is here: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/index.htm Read up on the [DOM](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/twebbrowser_oleobject.htm).

Comment: hmm yeah ive played around with this and i tried getting select.innerText but it returned the inner select text all in one chunk

Comment: @Stuayre Don't try to parse the HTML. Let the browser do it for you. It will get it right. Instead use the DOM.

Comment: @stuayre, if you managed to get the interface for your SELECT element, try casting it to IHTMLSelectElement  (or IHTMLSelectElement2, or IHTMLSelectElement4): that's what using the DOM means. Documentation for IHTMLSelectElement  is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768872(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Update: In year 2017+, TEmbeddedWb is not such a great choice. Check out the DCEF (chromium browser) in Delphi instead.

I know how to do that using TEmbeddedWB, originally from the now defunct site www.bsalsa.com, still available at [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/embeddedwb/) and [github](https://github.com/ghquant/Delphi-EmbeddedWB), which is a higher-performance and more feature-filled IE wrapper that replaces TWebBrowser You use something like this:

```
 procedure Dummy;
 var
    element: IHTMLElement;
 begin
    element := EmbeddedWB1.GetActiveElement;
 end;
```

Once you have the element, it's trivial to get its HTML from IHTMLElement.

I took all the TWebBrowser's out of my apps and put in TEmbeddedWB for a dozen great bug fixes, and features like this, such as in this case, it just makes getting active controls (like this html SELECT (drop down list) control) easy.

Comment: unfortunately the site is down

Comment: see the links above to github and sourceforge

Comment: many thanks. do you know if it still compiled with modern versions of Delphi?

Comment: So, you recommend Chromium over TEmbeddedWb ?

Comment: Absolutely. TEmbeddedWB is not a web browser, it's an alternative wrapper for IShellDocView which is just Internet Explorer which is a terrible, ancient, and not-very-useful browser to have in your app.

Comment: I need to edit a simple HTML and I just found out that this cannot be done in TChromium, so back to TEmbeddedWB :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120392/how-to-enable-editormode-in-tchromium?noredirect=1#comment71414937_42120392

Answer (score 2):

Using a `TWebBrowser` named `Wb` you can get your ids and texts this way:

```
uses MSHTML;

var
  Disp: IDispatch;
  SelEl: IHTMLSelectElement;
  i: Integer;
  OptionEl: IHTMLOptionElement;
  option_ids: array of WideString;
  option_texts: array of WideString;
begin
  // load test web page containing your SELECT
  Wb.Navigate('c:\temp\select.htm');
  // wait for browser to finish loading
  while Wb.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  // search the document for the SELECT element with the given name
  Disp:=(Wb.ControlInterface.Document as IHTMLDocument2).all.item('ship_to_method', EmptyParam);

  // EDIT: the following two lines are demonstrating how to get the element with focus 
  // simulate user selection by setting focus to SELECT element 
  (Disp as IHTMLElement2).focus;
  // now ask document for active element which should be the SELECT element
  Disp:=(Wb.ControlInterface.Document as IHTMLDocument2).activeElement;

  // basic error checking and acquiring of IHTMLSelectElement interface which is needed to access single OPTIONs within the SELECT
  if Assigned(Disp) and Supports(Disp, IHTMLSelectElement, SelEl) then
  begin
    // prepare array
    SetLength(option_ids, SelEl.length);
    SetLength(option_texts, SelEl.length);
    // get OPTIONs from SELECT
    for i:=0 to SelEl.length-1 do
    begin
      OptionEl := SelEl.Item(i,EmptyParam) as IHTMLOptionElement;
      // voila - read value and text of option element, store in arrays
      option_ids[i] := OptionEl.Value;
      option_texts[i] := OptionEl.Text;
    end;
  end;
  // option_ids now contains your IDs
  // option_texts now contains your texts
end;
```

Edit: added `option_texts` as well.

Edit2: This is the web page 'select.htm':

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<Select name="ship_to_method">
    <option value="1941">Royal Mail Standard Delivery at £1.45 </option>
    <option value="1942">Courier Standard Delivery  at £4.64 </option>
    <option value="1943">Royal Mail Priority Delivery at £1.66 </option>
    <option value="1944">Courier Priority Delivery at £5.15 </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about if there were two or twenty-seven Select tags in the document, and you wanted to get the focused one? Can the TWebBrowser tell you want HTML is currently focused? The OP talked about "what is selected". I wonder what they mean by selected? Focused? Active?

Comment: The `IHTMLDocument2` has a property `activeElement`. This might be it. So the `Disp` would then have to be acquired by `Disp:=(Wb.ControlInterface.Document as IHTMLDocument2).activeElement;`

Comment: @Warren P The MSDN says the following: "The active element retains focus in the parent document even when focus is shifted from the parent to another application. If the focus returns to the parent document, focus also returns to the same active element." So one element on the page is always active, plus it has the focus if the parent document has focus. If another page has the focus then the element is just active, not focused.