# Getting autocomplete googleMaps data into a Delphi combobox

Tags: delphi, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3

I am doing a Delphi transport application interacting with GoogleMaps APi and i would like to propose all "near by" names coming from the autocomplete Google Maps API when i enter the starting adress of the direction.

All of this will be displayed in a TCombobox when would be changed on the OnChange propertie.

Is that possible ??? ever heard of it ???

Thanks a lot
Gwenael

Answer (score 2):

There is a part of the Google Maps API called [The Google Places Autocomplete API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html). You can send requests (in the examples part of the reference page there is also the example with bounds for your purpose) as you will type in your combo box (ideally after some short delay for typos corrections). As the result you can receive either JSON or XML format file. After you parse it, you will get the list of appropriate suggestions.

I'm not sure with the [Google Maps API Key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html); if it's possible to use it in standalone application (and about the limitations) because I haven't implemented static part of the Google Maps yet.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought (assuming an approach which is based on remote controlling the web interface) was: this can be solved using [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) and friends ([IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), IHTMLElement etc.). See my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767229/delphi-how-can-i-get-a-select-from-a-twebbrowser-into-an-array/6778278#6778278) to get a feeling for this. You could use [Embedded Web Browser from bsalsa](http://www.bsalsa.com/) for easy access to all the Internet Explorer functionality.

My second thought was: there might be a part in the official API for this. But this I don't know. If there is none then the above approach could be a (work-intensive) workaround.

Comment: If you can let googleMaps do all the work for itself and just use the browser it's a LOT LESS WORK.  Then you can simply integrate its functionality with your app by sucking data out of the document object model DOM.   I would investigate both bSalsa's TEmbeddedWB or ChromiumEmbeddedFramework (CEF) for delphi.

Comment: @Gwenael - I would do it the same way; I mean let the web browser do what is intended for. And there is a lot of complete (with or without jQuery) examples like [this one](http://gmap3.net/examples/address-lookup.html) which you can simply copy paste to your web part of your application. About getting the data from this kind of a control I can't tell you anything more, but surely there will be also some with the standard controls. And about my answer; it is a solution, but consider you would have a limit of 1000 hits with a free API key what you can consume very quickly while typing.

Comment: @Warren P +1 for mentioning CEF. Didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

I have written a free and open source component that implements the Google Place Autocomplete and Google Place Details API's:

https://carbonsoft.co.za/components/

or

https://github.com/RynoCoetzee/TRCGPlaceAutoCompleteCombo