# How to enable EditorMode in TChromium?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, chromium-embedded

I would like to switch from TWebBrowser to DCEF3 (TChromium).
Can DCEF3 edit a HTML page? If yes, how to enable it to enter 'editor' mode?

Comment: CEF primarily gives you read-only access to the DOM and this restriction therefore also apply to DCEF3. If you can find a way to set the contentEditable attribute on the body-tag, then the HTML can be edited (you probably know that). However, there are no functions to inspect programmatically the element at the caret- or cursor-positions (there are functions to open the dev-tools, but that presumable isn't going to be helpful)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can execute Javascript in Chromium, you can achieve anything that can be done in Javascript.

So you could use this:

```
procedure TMainForm.EditMode1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if crm.Browser <> nil then
    crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
      'document.designMode = "on"', 'about:blank', 0);
end;

procedure TMainForm.EditModeOFF1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if crm.Browser <> nil then
    crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
      'document.designMode = "off"', 'about:blank', 0);
end;
```

For more details, you should google how to use Javascript to make an (Simple) HTML Editor.